# less command and syntax highlighting

Tags: bash, vim, vi, less, syntax-highlighting

I need  to use the `less command` with the syntax highlighting of the vim command for `python`, `C`, `bash` and other languages.

How do I apply syntax highlighting colors according to `vim` colors for `less command`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Syntax highlighting of `less`, works just fine on most *nix systems.

```
apt install source-highlight
export LESSOPEN="| /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS=' -R '
```

On Fedora/RedHat based distros use `/usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh` instead.

Even on Cygwin you can do it with the minor adjustment of the shell script path and installing with [`apt-cyg`](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) instead of `apt`.

However, using this drastically slows down browsing of large files. I suggest to use `alias` in such a way to only implement the `LESSOPEN` export above when needed, like this:

```
alias lessh='LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s" less -M '
```

where the `-M` flag is convenient to also show filename and line number.

Also remember to copy the script into your bin path:

```
cp /usr/share/source-highlight/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh
```

---

**UPDATE: 2019-07-24**

Apparently, on more recent Cygwin installs, you have the following files in your path:

```
source-highlight.exe
source-highlight-esc.sh
source-highlight-settings.exe
```

So now you also need to execute the `source-highlight-settings.exe` that will add the configuration file:
`$HOME/.source-highlight/source-highlight.conf`.

Comment: The alias 'lessh' doesn't work for me.  Running bash on osx.  Sigh.

Comment: That is an entirely different issue, most likely due to OSX using different shell and environment options, which may affect the interpretation of single and double quotes, differently. You can check and set these with [`shopt -p`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/shopt) and [`set`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/set).

Comment: This worked for me on OSX: first I installed with: `brew install source-highlight`, then I added an alias: `alias lessh='LESSOPEN="| src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s" less -R '`

Answer (score 57):

`less` doesn't support syntax highlighting.

`vim`, like all `vi` clones has a read-only mode called `view` which you can use to just view files.  it supports all features of vim including syntax highlighting.

e.g.

```
view filename.py
```

the main difference between `view` and `vi` is that view doesn't "lock" the file you're viewing by creating a .swp file.

Comment: if your `view command` means from `radare package` , it's not read only

Comment: Hmm, my `view` command doesn't seem to support syntax highlighting. I've tried `:syntax enable` and `:syntax on`, but I always get `syntax: Not an editor command`. My `vim` supports highlighting, though.

Comment: @felix - do you have another `vi` like `nvi` or `elvis` installed?  check your `/usr/bin/view` - on my debian system, it's a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/view` which is, in turn, a symlink to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.

Comment: Hmm, in my case it's a symlink to `/usr/bin/ex`, which, curiously, is owned by the `vi` package.

Comment: ah, but which `vi` package? vim? elvis? nvi?

Comment: I can confirm what @Felix says, on `arch linux` `view` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/ex` of `core/vi` package.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/244029/185665): `alias vless='vim -u $VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.vim'`

Comment: To use highlighting in a pipe, like `grep something somewhere | less` use this on vi: `grep something somewhere | view -`

Comment: Erm, `less` **does** support syntax highlighting on 3 out of 3 of my systems...

Comment: "`less` doesn't support syntax highlighting" -- incorrect, see [this answer instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139787/78245).

Comment: @JoshM. You are wrong. `less` **doesn't** support syntax highlighting. It can, however, be configured to pipe the input data through other programs that transform it in various ways (including applying colour codes for syntax highlighting). The answer you refer to is **NOT** `less` doing syntax highlighting, it is calling an external program via the `LESSPIPE` variable (and adding the `-R` option via the `LESS` var) - note that using LESSPIPE just for syntax highlighting replaces the ability to view many other file types, incl. the file list of tar, deb, etc as well as the text layer of PDFs.

Comment: `less` comes with a `/usr/bin/lesspipe` AKA `lessfile` script which does all that and more (incl. viewing of compressed files) by setting `LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s"` - and it would certainly be possible to write a modified version of lesspipe which used a source highlighter for source code input while retaining the other features provided by lesspipe. None of the answers here do that, they replace the existing functionality of lesspipe with a script that does just syntax highlighting (the src-hilite-lesspipe.sh script in source-highlight does a little more but not as much as lesspipe).

Answer (score 19):

I tend to disagree with Ingo, `less` **can** be taught to highlight syntax. Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/71593/32884) on SuperUser. Basically, you have to install GNU's source-highlight (available in all major distro package repos), and then add the following to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` or what have you):

```
export LESSOPEN="| /path/to/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
export LESS=" -R "
```

However, note that `source-highlight` is not as powerful as `vim`'s highlighter. Use whatever suits you best.

Answer (score 14):

`less` requires third-party tools to highlight syntax elements, but Vim can be used as a pager, i.e. a replacement for `less`. There are more advanced plugins, but the basic script actually ships with Vim (`$VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.sh`). For the full information, see [Using vim as a syntax-highlighting pager](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_syntax-highlighting_pager) on the Vim Tips Wiki.

If you're already using Vim, the consistency (and support of almost any file type) makes this worth a try.

Comment: I'm surprised people doesn't even bother to Google before posting wrong answers...

Comment: @user1147688: If you carefully read Felix's answer, the GNU source-highlight is an external program, and the integration with less is very loose. It's not `less` that does the highlighting; but Vim indeed has this capability built-in.

Comment: For the question "How do I apply syntax highlighting colors according to vim colors for less command?", the answer "By using source-highlight" seems like a more correct answer that "By using vim".

Comment: +1 but I'm sure what these comments are trying to say -- can't tell if they're even positive or negative ("...google before posting wrong answers"?, "installing xyz is more correct than just using vim"?).  This answer is clearly the "most correct answer". Basically the OP didn't know this feature of vim existed, and this answer lets the OP know that it exists. Occam's razor ftw. The answer could only be improved by showing an example, e.g., `$ diff file1.c file2.c | /usr/share/vim/vim74/macros/less.sh`

Answer (score 1):

After dabbling in some of the answers above, I think the most configuration-free solution is to just install and use `vimpager`.

It is available [on github](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager), [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/vimpager), [Arch (older version)](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/vimpager/), [AUR (latest)](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vimpager-git/), and maybe more.

After install you should be able to immediately use `vimpager` instead of `less` at your shell.

To utilise `vimpager` in other instances where `less` is used, you can change the `PAGER` variables your [shell config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))  (`.bashrc` etc.) by adding:

```
export PAGER=/usr/local/bin/vimpager
export MANPAGER=/usr/local/bin/vimpager
```

The install paths may (need to?) be different on OSX, but this works fine on Arch linux.

You can then set an `alias` to always substitute `less` for `vimpager`, in the same file:

```
alias less=$PAGER
```

(As described at the github readme)

Comment: I'm using vimpager on osx but I don't see syntax highlighting like when I do `http localhost:8000|vimpager`