# Git pager is less, but what is causing the output coloring?

Tags: colors, git, diff, pager, colordiff

`less` itself isn't capable of doing syntax highlighting, according to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90990/less-command-and-syntax-highlighting).

However, `git diff` nicely shows colored output in less, its default pager. When I redirect the output of `git diff` into a file, no color escape sequences are visible.

Does `git diff` know where it's being sent, and formats the output accordingly? How would one do that?

---

I just noticed that git colors the `diff` output (e.g. `git diff`), however, it doesn't know how to syntax highlighting in general. e.g.

```
git show 415fec6:log.tex
```

doesn't enable any TeX-like syntax.

---

Reading the `git` sources, I found the following hints

in `diff.h`:

```
int use_color;
```

---

I was previously referring to *syntax highlighting*, but that was not correct. What I mean is output coloring, see e.g.

[image: example color output]

Comment: Do you have any real syntax highlighting, or just the red and green color for removed and added lines?

Comment: BTW: to get git colouring into less: `git diff --color=always | less -r`  (or `less -R` for ANSI). BTW: for other commands that don't paginate by default (`git diff` does) you can switch it on: `git -p some_git_command`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Git uses `isatty()` to check whether stdout is a tty: this is used to see if a pager must be used ([pager.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/pager.c)) as well as colors ([color.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/color.c)).

Answer (score 14):

Running:

```
git diff --color=always > output
```

shows the color escapes.

Damn I found it in `git`'s `color.c` file:

```
static int check_auto_color(void)                                           
{                                                                           
  if (color_stdout_is_tty < 0)                                              
    color_stdout_is_tty = isatty(1);                                        
  if (color_stdout_is_tty || (pager_in_use() && pager_use_color)) {         
    char *term = getenv("TERM");                                            
    if (term && strcmp(term, "dumb"))                                       
      return 1;                                                             
  }                                                                         
  return 0;                                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`less` can support colour with `-r` `--raw-control-chars` and `-R` `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`

You could use Pythons [`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/) to do the highlighting and pipe it in.

To combine it all configure a less filter [as described on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/117841/get-colors-in-less-command)

Comment: the link is indeed interesting, thanks. Do you know if `git` is actually using pygmentize? Because it is not listed as a dependency.

Comment: btw, when I run `git diff` the child `less` process is not appended by any option (neither `-R` nor `-r`). However, I don't know if git calls it in a special way and thus the args are not visible in `htop`.

Comment: `git` outputs the colour escape code it's self. It's also written in `c` so adding Python would be a huge dependency. It might be able to control `less` via the environment

Comment: maybe via the `LESS` env var?

Comment: Yes, LESS=FRX is added to the environment (see [pager.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/398dd4bd039680ba98497fbedffa415a43583c16/pager.c)).